# Add id also in dynamic URLs like in stack overflows URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I had some alert components when each clicked; it will get redirected to a page

```
 <div className="question11">
            {data.map((itm) => (
              <Link
                key={itm._id}
                href={{
                  pathname: "/[itm]",
                  query: { id: itm._id },
                }}
                as={`/${encodeURIComponent(
                  itm.Name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 - _ . ~]/g, "").replace(
                    / /g,
                    "-"
                  )
                )}`}
              >
                <Alert className="question13">{itm.Name}</Alert>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
```

The redirected page has a URL in the following pattern
`http://localhost:3000/itm.Name`. Example: http://localhost:3000/spiderman-no-way-home-release-date-in-india. I am passing `itm._id` for accessing the corresponding data on the redirected page

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  var id1 = context.query.id;

  // console.log(context.query.id);
  const queryRequest = fetch("https://askover.wixten.com/questone/" + id1).then(
    async (res) => await res.json()
  );
```

When I click on alert components, I can pass the `itm._id`, and the page is redirected properly. The issue occurs when I manually enter the URL in the browser.The issue here is not getting the `itm._id` from the alert component. The answer that I came up with here is to create an API to access the API by passing the `itm.Name`, but that will require deconstructing the `itm.Name` to its original form, and `itm.Name` might not be unique every time is there another method by which I can access `itm._id` itself also, if I can use the URL in  http://localhost:3000/itm._id/itm.Name
this format also, I think it will be okay just as StackOverflow does it.

Comment: _"if i can use the url in `http://localhost:3000/itm._id/itm.Name` this format also i think it will be ok"_ - Then why don't you do just that, and use a dynamic page like `/pages/[id]/[slug].js`? That way you can extract the `id` value to make the request against the API, but still have the slugged name on the URL.

Comment: can u walk me throgh what i must be doing inorder to make those changes  with an answer @juliomalves

Comment: change pathname to itm._id

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page you will lose the context, even if you use some store(local, session, etc) that will not work for the user visiting your app for the first time.

**One thing always remains is URL, neither storage nor context.**
To solve this kind of issue, what you can do is pass the id and slug parameters to the URL and read whenever requires.

**Check more details [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props)**

**Next.js Directory**

- pages

  - index.js
  - [id]

    - [slug].js

The URL will look something like this: **https://localhost:3000/123/my-post-slug**
, Slug is optional, It'll help for SEO purposes.

**[slug].js**

```
const Component = (props) => (
  <div>
    <h1>{props.title}</h1>
    <p>{props.content}</p>
  </div>
);


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const id = context.params.id;
  const data = fetch(`https://askover.wixten.com/questone/${id}`).then((res) => await res.json());
  return {
    props: data,
  }
}
```

Comment: thanx for the answer @RAHUL SHARMA  but ur answer does not answer what changes must i make in the alert componet and what must be the condents of id.js

Comment: Why do you need id.js that should be a directory, according to my approach?

Comment: @meon onclick you should redirect to this URL that's it.

Comment: `<Link
                key={itm._id}
                href={{
                  pathname: "/[itm]",
                  query: { id: itm._id },
                }}
                as={`/${encodeURIComponent(
                  itm.Name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 - _ . ~]/g, "").replace(
                    / /g,
                    "-"
                  )
                )}`}
              >
                <Alert className="question13">{itm.Name}</Alert>
              </Link>` what changes must i make in this   as u can see i am creating slug as itm.Name and id is itm._id

Comment: You can try this `<Link href={{ pathname: '[id]/[slug]', query: { slug: 'my-post', id:123 } }}>`

Comment: so accoiding to my question `query: { slug: 'my-post', id:123 }` must be somthing like this `query: { slug: itm.Name.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 - _ . ~]/g, "").replace( / /g, "-" ) ', id:itm._id}` is this corect  @Rahul Sharma

Comment: @meon Yes, It's a simple string that should be fine, You are not dependent on this it doesn't even metter.